# If $x$ and $y$ are nonzero vectors in $R^n$ whose lengths are equal to each other ,then $x-y$ is orthogonal to $x+y$.Is it true ,if true ,show it

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x$ and $y$ are nonzero vectors in $R^n$ whose lengths are equal to each other, then $x-y$ is orthogonal to $x+y$.Is it true, if true, show it.

I am stuck in showing this question , it seems like true but I cannot prove it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you sure that no assumption is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product of $x-y$ and $x+y$ is $(x-y)^T(x+y)=x^Tx + x^Ty -y^Tx -y^Ty=|x|^2-|y|^2=0$

so, $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ are orthogonal

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Simplify the expression $\langle x-y, x+y\rangle$ using the following rules:

1. $\langle z, u+v\rangle = \langle z,u\rangle + \langle z, v\rangle$
2. $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle v, u\rangle$
3. $\langle \alpha u, v \rangle = \alpha \langle u, v\rangle$.

also, use the fact that $\langle x,x\rangle = \langle y,y\rangle$.